# No error on sql Delete But Don't delete the record (except if i use Firstname in Where clause)

Tags: java, sql

I create A method that deletes a persons name on my database. Using firstname(where clause) the sql command is working and successfully deletes the record . However using the "Lastname" in sql command works but doesn't deletes the record. I have an input of lastname, before it was firstname

```
public static void deletePerson (String lname ) {

     String  host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Students";
     String username = "username";
     String password = "password";
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);

            // this is not working, I dont know what wrong with this ione
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Lastname = ?");
        statement.setString(2, lname);
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
        System.out.println("worrrk");


          // this is the working
        //PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Firstname = ?");
        //statement.setString(1, fname);



    } catch (SQLExcepton e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `statement.setString(2, lname);` be `statement.setString(1, lname);`? You only have 1 parameter so...

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the steps you've taken...

You've created a `PreapredStatement`, good...

```
PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Lastname = ?");
```

You've set the parameter value...incorrectly...

```
statement.setString(2, lname);
```

There's only one parameter so should be

```
statement.setString(1, lname);
```

You closed the `statement`...

```
statement.close();
```

Wait, what?  Did you intend to actually "execute" some command against the database?

Try inserting `statement.executeUpdate()` before `statement.close();`

Now we've covered that, let's discuss your (lack) of resource management...

If something were to go wrong between `Connection connect = ...` and `connect.close()`, the `connect.close()` (and probably the `statement.close()`) statements would never be executed, leaving database resources open but not doing anything (been wasted)...

Luckily for us, Java 7+ makes it easy to manage this now, for example

```
try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password)) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Lastname = ?")) {

        statement.setString(1, lname);
        int rowsDeleted = statement.executeUpdate();
        // You could inspect the number of rows deleted
        System.out.println("worrrk");

    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

**Updated**

In some cases, the `Connection` may not be set to auto commit, so you will need to do it manually, so after `int rowsDeleted = statement.executeUpdate();` you should call `connection.commit();` before you close the `PreparedStatement` or `Connection

```
try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password)) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Lastname = ?")) {

        statement.setString(1, lname);
        int rowsDeleted = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (!connect.getAutoCommit()) { 
            connect.commit();
        }
        // You could inspect the number of rows deleted
        System.out.println("worrrk");

    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Takendarkk Shhh, you're spoiling the fun ;)

Comment: I'm just happy I can spot things like that every once in a while. It means my eyes haven't left me completely.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I put statement.executeUpdate() before statement.close();
run it. but the result did no change

Comment: @watata Sorry, got distracted by other things, you may also need to call `Connection#commit`, see update...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I copied ur code to try but, still don't work.
I observe another behavior on my program. 

I input a firstname on my txnameField (JtextFied) 
it delete the record, the firstname was with the column 1 of my database.

but using the LnameField dont work...

Comment: @watata The column position in the database is irrelevant, it's only the position of the parameter in the `PreparedStatement` that matters.  Verify that the name you are trying to delete exists and that the value are giving and the value in the database are the same

Comment: @watata Depending on you database you may need to ensure that the case is correct

Answer (score 0):

Change your `statement.setString(2, lname);` to `statement.setString(1, lname);`

The first argument of [PreparedStatement.setString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) is parameterIndex. In your case, there is only one parameter in the SQL clause, so it should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistaskes

- PreparedStatement should set `statement.setString(1,lname)` as there is only 1 parameter (i.e **?**) in your query .
- You should call **statement.executeUpdate** in order to execute Query before `statement.close`

You might have misunderstood the way preparedStatement works , So here [JDBC: PreparedStatement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) is a small tutorial to brush up your skills

Now coming to

```
      // this is the working
    //PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE Firstname = ?");
    //statement.setString(1, fname);
```

Why this statement is working , it's working because you are actually setting the correct parameter (i.e **1**) , this above statement is not working because you have used **fname** try the same with **lname** It will also work

**Note :** The setter methods of  PreparedStatement `ps.setXXX(parameterNo,value)` here parameterNo does not correspond to the column of Table in backend ,it's the parameter present in query .